# What to do when existing answers to your question (with a bounty) are wrong or very incomplete?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

I've recently asked this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262233/sampling-distribution-from-two-independent-bernoulli-populations-current-answer), and I have two answers. One is very incomplete, lacking the most important cases. The other one I think is completely incorrect, although 'apparently intuitive'. First, am I correct in this assessment?

Second, if both answers stay there, most likely some potential 'answerers' will  not even try to answer the question.

Should I ask the users to remove their answers?

Comment: I think wrong answers *increase* the chances to get a good answer (because they increase the visibility of the post) instead of decreasing them. If you think an answer is wrong, or critically incomplete, comment to say so and downvote. That's all you need to do really.

Comment: @amoeba: Moreover, wrong answers can provoke the ["something is wrong on the internet"](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/duty_calls.png) reflex.

Comment: @Scortchi =D First time hearing about that! =D

Comment: You should leave comment &/or downvote answers that are incomplete & incorrect.

Comment: In essence, awarding a bounty gives you a decision on which post gets it, but it doesn't confer any scope or obligation to do anything you could not or would not do in any other thread. You're not expected to manage the thread.

Comment: You could offer a new bounty.

Answer (score 2):

I then added a bounty and received a good answer.